# How do you pronounce Betelgeuse? (I'm afraid I don't get the joke)

Tags: pronunciation

**Betelgeuse** is a red giant (some say supergiant) star in the constellation **Orion**. You can easily spot it on a clear night: it's at a straight angle to **Orion's Belt**, and it's reddish (more so than **Mars**). It's pretty impressive. I recommend you find it and point it out to your friends. People really should look up at the sky now and then.

That said, I thought you were supposed to pronounce it as ***Beatle Jews***.

Now it turns out there's this kitsch-y comedy from the Year of Our Lord's Grace 1988, titled "Beetlejuice," in which there's a character (a ghost, I think, I didn't see the whole movie) from Betelgeuse whose name is ***Beetle Juice***. Either it's a tacky joke of some sort, or I'm missing something here. I'm not a movie buff.

What am I missing? What's the joke?

Comment: According to [at least one dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/betelgeuse), it is normal to pronounce Betelgeuse exactly the same as "beetle juice".

Comment: In school, I was taught to pronounce it phonetically as "batelgize" (long "a"; long "i").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the joke is that *Betelgeuse* is an unfamiliar name, and therefore sounds made-up and nonsensical.  It adds to the [absurd humor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surreal_humour) of the film when a viewer discovers that *Beetlejuice* is a variation of a real word.

Incidentally, Betelgeuse is due to go supernova soon, at least in the cosmic sense of "soon."  It could happen many thousands of years from now, or it could happen tomorrow.  (Or to be more precise, the light from its explosion hundreds of years ago could reach us tomorrow.)  When we do see it explode, it's predicted to be as bright as the full moon.  As a fan of *Beetlejuice*, it amuses me to look at Betelgeuse and say its name three times, hoping it'll explode just then.

Answer (score 8):

The type of joke is called [cacography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cacography) - the deliberate misspelling of a word.

In this case you end up with two "new" words that seemingly make sense.

Just say **beatle jews** and **beetle juice** aloud and not overly pronounced. They should sound largely the same.

Whether you find that funny or not is largely a matter of taste. (And as with so many jokes, it loses a lot of "funnyness" if explained.)

Answer (score 3):

It's more of a homonym, no? It's not a misspelling, since there really is a thing in the sky with that name/spelling. Beetle Juice is a funny movie which had attained a cult-ish status with Alec Baldwin, Micheal Keaton, Geena Davis, and the lovey Winona Ryder. The main character's name, the goulish one, played by Michael Keaton, is spelled the same way as your beloved red giant. I don't think he actually comes from the red giant, that would appear to be the common thread...

What is the joke you are referring to?

Comment: "What is the joke you are referring to?" That's what I've been wondering.

Answer (score 2):

I recall when the movie came out that it was originally to be "Betelgeuse" but was changed.  Today [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beetlejuice) shows

> The character of Betelgeuse — envisioned by McDowell as a winged demon who takes on the form of a short Middle Eastern man — is also intent on killing the Deetzes

[Wikipedia also notes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betelgeuse)

> Betelgeuse (/ˈbiːtəldʒuːz/, /ˈbɛtəldʒuːz/, /ˈbiːtəldʒɜrz/[1] or /ˈbiːtəldʒuːs/[2]), also known by its Bayer designation Alpha Orionis …

So "jews" is the first listed, and "juice" is the last. The last is also the funniest.

For a "real" pronunciation, you need to ask someone who speaks Arabic as it sounded in medeval times, and have a native english (only) speaker try and repeat it.

But the word comes to us via the French *Bételguse* so "jews" is right (sort of: no /d/ before the /ʒ/, and it's "beta" not "beet a".  Repeating what Google says in French as an American speaking English, "betel-" rhymes with "petal".  But it does lean towards an (english) "long e" and may be heard as such.

Try it yourself using Google Translate, asking for the French. That will vary far less than English interpretations, and will always sound knowledgeable and not silly. Especially true since astronomers are an international multi-language crowd.

Comment: The French pronunciation and the Arabic pronunciation are not the proper model for the English pronunciation, any more than for other words that have come from Arabic through French like *zero, azimuth, cipher*.

Answer (score 1):

I learned the stars in Orion's belt from my Grandfather before the movie came out. When he taught the stars name to me he used Bet-el-gus with a hard "g" to pronounce it. Although, he did say others pronounced the name Beetle-Juice. I always thought there were two accepted pronunciations. This was before the movie Beetlejuice came out. I did think of my grandfather when the movie came out, making the connection of movie title to star name. I say the movie name is coincidence to the star. Also, it seems to pronunciation difference is just preference for people.

Comment: It's no coincidence: the character was named Betelgeuse after the star and was midle-eastern in the original script.

Answer (score 1):

Bet-el-gurz.. No beat,  no juice.
In Britain we still have a monthly astronomy programme called 'The Sky at Night'. It originated in the early 1950's and was introduced by Mr Patrick Moore. His pronunciation is reliable.

Comment: Evidently the pronunciation is not reliable, since the consensus of credible sources is approximately that given in the question, "beetle juice" and definitely not "bet-el-gurz". Etymology would agree, since the original Arabic (after misread into Latin) had a long 'a' sound at the start (you use a short 'e', consensus is a long 'e') and used the 'j' sound in the middle (matching consensus, and not your 'g' at all).

Comment: Betelgeux. I suspect the film is in fact solely responsible for American pronunciation. I had never heard it pronounced as beetle juice beforehand. I could cite a british astronomer from the 1960s Sky at Night. Can anyone produce any other astronomer calling it beetle juice before 1988? Then we could have a discussion. Im 64 and studied astronomy.

Comment: No, you have a claim of remembering something from when you were a child, and not remembering something else from during your life. I suspect your pronunciation is incorrect and in a vanishingly small minority, arising from a "read what you see" process instead of actually knowing the correct pronunciation.

Comment: Thanks for bothering to respond. I didnt mean to inferr I recalled it. I recently watched a  contemporary episode with Patrick alluding to Alpha Orionis by the British pronunciation in a recorded episode. One can argue the toss about 'correct' pronunciation.It seems to be that in Britain at least no-one used the now popular US styling. Im inclined to see culture as the main influence....very probably the choice of a single person in 1988 (Tim Burton knows), then later popularised by the internet. I suspect if 'beetle juice' was realised as correct it would have been rejected as flippant.